# Placing image after text without adding space between lines

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

In this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/spdvoc06/ last line is stretched to place the image. Can anyone please help to fix it? I need to place second image after text without adding space between lines.

```
<img src="https://www.getdesignschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/up.jpg" alt="" width="56" height="44" />
<p style="display:inline;">I want to learn how to design but I spend so much time just reading I never remember it all. I need something that teaches me in practical way, and gives me feed-back on what I've created...
</p>
<img src="https://www.getdesignschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/bottom.jpg" alt="" width="56" height="44" />
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the issue and what you want to get in the end? Your question is not very clear at the moment.

Comment: I suggest you read more about CSS. It allows you to do just that. More specifically, read about the "position" attribute.

Comment: @Bastiaan I want the image to be moved down a little and don't add space between lines

Comment: ^Check out my answer, got it working ^_^

Comment: Thanks, I should have read about position:absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:absolute` to the last image

https://jsfiddle.net/y93su8s1/2/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all that needs to be added to accomplish this is on the last picture a "vertical-align:top"

I added it and copied the code for you. Hope this helps!

```
   <img style="vertical-align:top" src="https://www.getdesignschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/bottom.jpg" alt="" width="56" height="44" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/spdvoc06/

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display:inline-block` and `width` to `paragraph` will fix it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/spdvoc06/1/